# I am using pandas to check user input in multiple columns, i want output as entire row which matches input

Tags: pandas

below is my code:

```
for r in cols:
    full_row_of_matched = cols[cols.isin([input_ip]).any(axis=1)]
    exact_column = list(cols.columns[cols.eq(input_ip).any(0)])
    res = full_row_of_matched.iloc[:, 1]
```

Below is the DF

```
eth0      eth1        eth2         server_group  vars
10.1.0.1  172.10.1.3  172.10.11.3  A             xyz
10.1.0.2  172.10.1.3  172.10.11.9  B             abc
10.1.0.7  172.10.1.9  172.10.1.3   V             qwe
```

in the above Df you can see ip 172.10.1.3 has duplicates, so if i provide input as 172.10.1.3 i need below output

```
IP provided 172.10.1.3 has been assigned to host xyz and mapped to interface eth1
IP provided 172.10.1.3 has been assigned to host abc and mapped to interface eth1
IP provided 172.10.1.3 has been assigned to host qwe and mapped to interface eth2
```

Comment: can you be more explicit? What would be an example of user input and the matching expected output?

Comment: please check if the edited question is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### fetching matching rows (option1)

```
inp = '172.10.1.3'
(df
 .melt(id_vars=['server_group', 'vars'], value_name='IP', var_name='interface')
 .loc[lambda d: d['IP'].eq(inp)]
)
```

output:

```
  server_group vars interface          IP
3            A  xyz      eth1  172.10.1.3
4            B  abc      eth1  172.10.1.3
8            V  qwe      eth2  172.10.1.3
```

##### fetching matching rows (option2)

```
inp = '172.10.1.3'
df[df.eq(inp).any(1)]
```

or, to limit to the "eth" columns:

```
inp = '172.10.1.3'
df[df.filter(like='eth').eq(inp).any(1)]
```

output:

```
        eth0        eth1         eth2. server_group. vars
0  10.1.0.1.  172.10.1.3  172.10.11.3.             A  xyz
```

##### older answer

Your question is unclear, but assuming you have `inp` as input, you could use:

```
inp = '172.10.1.3'

cols = list(df.columns[df.eq(inp).any(0)])

cols
# ['eth1']
```

If you want all combinations of matching row/col indices:

```
inp = '172.10.1.3'

import numpy as np
rows, cols = np.where(df.eq(inp))
indices = list(zip(df.index[rows], df.columns[cols]))
```

output: `[(0, 'eth1')]`

Comment: Sorry for unclear info, say suppose my input = 172.10.1.3 or whatever, pandas should check that in all columns that as IP's and if match found, it has to print the entire row.

Comment: also the input provided may not exist in any of the columns

Comment: Sure, it works, then you'll get no rows in the output, provide an updated to the question if you want a different output

Comment: then `out = df[df.filter(like='eth').eq(inp).any(1)] ; print('no match') if out.isempty() else print(out)`

Comment: if there is duplicate entries in multiple columns, it should print hostname column and  column name of duplicate entires

Comment: Isn't is what it is already doing?

Comment: `
for r in cols:
    full_row_of_matched = cols[cols.isin([input_ip]).any(axis=1)]
    exact_column = list(cols.columns[cols.eq(input_ip).any(0)])
    res = full_row_of_matched.iloc[:, 1]
`

i am using above code to print result in loop, problem i am facing is, if two servers has same ip assigned, it should print server_name and interface twice but exact_column variable is not updating the list but its over writing

Comment: I'll rephrase, how is the current answer not filling your needs? If you need to provide code, please update your question

Comment: any way i can reach you out? may be i am failing to explain you in better way

Comment: best is to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71938549/edit) your question to provide enough details (show another example of input/output that matches your "duplicate entries" case)

Comment: i have updated my question

Comment: @harsha_606 check the update, but please don't change the logic anymore, if you have further changes ask a new question

Comment: thank you so much for your patience and help, kindly let me know where i can learn pandas in better way

Comment: I would start with the fantastic [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html#user-guide)